# Using temperature as feature in Neural Network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, forecasting, deep-learning, feature-selection

I'm currently putting together a Neural Network for doing Sales Forecasting for hundreds of products. The domain experts know that the sales spike when the temperature drops and so I started to use temperature as a feature in my feature-set for an Artificial Neural Network. I'm getting quite sufficient results (getting the model to overfit) on the entire dataset with the train loss at about 0.20 and validation loss at about 0.50.

However, after tuning quite a bit of hyper-parameters, the losses won't go down. They seem to be have reached a plateau around the two loss marks that they can't break through. At this time, I'm starting to think that something is wrong with the data, and that temperature might not be a good feature. My question is that should I continue my search to tune and find the optimal hyper-parameters, or do I need to re-structure my dataset?

The dataset itself contains historical sales/temperature data organized into weekly intervals going back to 2007. As for the length of the data, it's about 60,000 rows.

Also I'm a Software Dev by profession and fairly new to Neural Networks/Data Science but not completely beginner so feel free to give me any advice you can.

Thanks!

Comment: Sales data from, say, 2007 - 2011 will have patterns that are quite different than sales data from, say, 2013-now, due to the Great Recession and its aftermath.  Furthermore, depending on what you are forecasting, you may be impacted by holiday sales spikes that move around during the course of the year or within the week.   Why do you think the issue is the temperature data?

Comment: Thanks for the response! Prior to using 2007+ data, I had used 2010+ data and during that iteration, the model did overfit but had train loss of 0.12 and a val-loss of 0.61. So i guess it makes sense as to why the train loss went up during the iteration of 2007+ data. However couldn’t that be because I added more data? I don’t think holiday sales are a big factor simply because the data trend, for this specific family class plotted out, was quite stationary. Also, I thought it was temperature because I wasn’t sure if temperature itself would be a good idea to use as a feature.